# Approval Status can not be update

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-addin, content-approval

I'm a newbie in Sharepoint.
Now I'm working in a company which has Sharepoint 2010 systems
I want to create a content approval workflow. 
For the beginning, I was trying to create content approval only (without workflow)
But when I click the item and choose approve, It failed to update approval status
No matter how much I try to approve it, item status remains pending.

I thought the problem is because "Workflow can use app permission" features has been inactive, but when I check it, there is no that features on my Site features lists.

[image: my site features lists]

I have 2 problems here.

1. I can not update my content approval status, even I tried it manually
2. There is no "Workflow can use app permission" on site features lists

If someone know about the reason and solution to my problems, I would be very grateful
Thank you very much

Comment: Is it ootb approval workflow or custom approval workflow?

Comment: @Jinxed it is ootb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

- Deactivate and reactivate two Site Collection features: Workflows and Publishing Approval Workflow.
- Grant Edit access to the specific task list for the workflow to the affected user.

Comment: I already did your solutions. But it didn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. I found this article http://sharepoint-for-real.blogspot.com/2014/06/sharepoint-approval-workflow-vs-content.html. 
My custom lists are associated with a content type. Is this the reason why I can change the approval status, although I did it manually by clicking approve/reject button on the ribbon? I'm really confuse now

Comment: UPDATE! It worked. For first minute, I thought it failed. But after a hour, I tried again and it work now. Thank you very much sir..